# migration cakephp application from 2.x to 3.x

Tags: cakephp, migration

There is a large application which developed in cakephp version 2.0. Now I would like to migrate it 3.x.  When I have tried to start migrate then got a lot of obstacle

like in 2.x used

```
App::import('Controller', str_replace('Controller', '', $controller));
```

Now in 3.x how can handle it? Actually i need to know is there any good option to migrate? Is there any reference?

Comment: Have you read this? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html

Comment: Are you looking for a way to import a `Controller` in Cakephp 3 or to do a `use` statement with a variable?

Comment: Also read [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2015/06/06/cakephp-3-0-migration-notes/) maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the `App::import()` anymore as CakePHP 3 Follows [PSR-4](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#namespaces) and you can load your classes using `use` like this `use App\Controller\AppController;`. Search more for PSR-4 autoloading.

In the official site says that there is a [tool](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#upgrade-tool) but on github it mentions that it is still under development.